# Testing functions that require input with Pytest

Tags: pytest

I need your help. I'm working on my final CS50P project and I finished writing my project code. Now I need to write a test code that implements tests for at least 3 functions that can be testet with Pytest. But my functions don't return anything, they do something. Inside main I run a loop:

```
while True:
        
        selection = input("Please select from the following options (enter number): ")
        print("")

        if selection == "1":
            some_function()
            **again()**
```

again() consists of the following:

```
def again():
    _ = input("Do you want to return to the main menu? If not, enter 'n': ")
    if _ == "n":
        sys.exit("Good-bye  \n")
    else:
        print("")
```

How do you test again() with pytex? It doesn't take any arguments. I tried reading up on how to add parameters to the function test, but the chapter on parametrization in the docs doesn't seem to be the right one. I don't want to send a number of tests at once. I want to send one test with arguments, so I can see if I achieve the right outcome.

Here's what I tried:

```
with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
        again("n")
```

That of course doesn't work, because again() doesn't take any arguments. And if I only want to ask if again() does trigger the question, that also doesnt work :( [image: see screenshot]

Found this code on an advanced stackoverflow question that I thought could be adapted to my situation, but I don't know how to do it properly. Won't work:

```
def test_again(self):
    again__.input = lambda: ''
    output = again__("n")
    assert output == "Thank you! Good-bye "
```

This following code passes the test (another stack overflow find), but I have no idea what I'm testing with this, probably not that we're exiting the system if the user enters 'n'?

```
def test_again(monkeypatch):
# monkeypatch the "input" function, so that it returns "n".
# This simulates the user entering "n" in the terminal:
    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda _: "n")
    # go about using input() like you normally would:
    _ = input("the question?")
    assert _ == "n"
```

Any hints for a **beginner**?

Comment: I think I was able to test if it exits or not, but still not really sure how to properly apply this. monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda _: "y")
    assert again() == None
    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda _: "n")
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
        again()